# Atribuir a vários elementos valores diferentes usando mesma função

Tags: jquery

Veja, tenho 5 IDS(5 elementos DOM) e preciso, usando a função text() do JQuery, adicionar a cada um deles um texto diferente, posso fazer assim..

```
$("#ID1").text("bla");

$("#ID2").text("blabla");
```

**....**

Existe uma maneira, menor, simplificada, de fazer isso, se os textos fossem iguais, poderia separar por vírgula os seletores, mas não são..

Pensei em algo como:

```
.text(function() {
$("#ID1") = "bla";
$("#ID2") = "blabla";
});
```

Enfim, alguma sugestão, até mesmo para boa prática e para manter o código simplificado e limpo.

Comment: De onde vem esse texto? dá para ter esse texto numa array para fazer o código mais auto-mágico? Outra pergunta:  as ID diferem somente pelo numero?

Comment: veja esse exemplo utilizando uma funçãozinha básica: http://jsfiddle.net/z7Leskqb/

Comment: Alexandre viste o meu comment em cima?

Comment: @Sergio, o texto é estático, ele não é gerado randomicamente, ou de qualquer forma, mas são 5 textos diferentes. Dá para coloca-lo em um array. As IDS não se diferem por números, elas são totalmente diferentes.

Comment: Interessante @WallaceMaxters, vou ver melhor como funciona!

Answer (score 2):

```js
  var addText = function(array, element){
         
        $(element).each(function(i){
            $(this).text(array[i]);
        }); 
    };
    
    $(function(){
      var array = [
          "meu primeiro texto",
          "Meu segundo Texto",
          "Meu terceiro texto",
          "E assim por diante",
       ];
     
        addText(array, '.CLASS');
    });


    addText(array, '[id^=ID]');
```

```css
.CLASS{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CLASS"></div>
    <div class="CLASS"></div>
    <div class="CLASS"></div>
    <div class="CLASS"></div>
    <div class="CLASS"></div>
```

Comment: Olha só uma outra maneira quase igual, mas que me parece mais idiomática em jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/nLxn4wpk/

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um objeto formato dicionário, onde as chaves são os IDs das divs, e os valores são os respectivos textos. Depois basta percorrer o dicionário para preencher as divs:

```js
var textos = {
    "id1" : "bla",
    "id2" : "blabla",
    "foo" : "bar" // , etc
};
$.each(textos, function(chave, valor) {
   $('#' + chave).text(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: @Wallace Maxters, deu uma solução perfeita.

Comment: Se as classes fizerem sentido, a solução dele é boa sim. Mas a minha tem algum problema para merecer o voto contra?

Comment: Tem sim. Existem muitas soluções boas e mais recomendadas que esta, no caso a do amigo, @Wallace Maxters. Também já passei por isso. Criei uma solução, mas deram-me negativo, NÃO PORQUE ESTAVA ERRADA, mas sim por que não era a melhor solução. Você é moderador, vai entender: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45287/criptografar-senha-e-se-logar-php-e-pdo/45304#45304

Comment: Eu não concordo, mas ok. Sobre a sua outra resposta, aqui não é o lugar para discutirmos. Se quiser, pode abrir uma discussão sobre o assunto no [meta].

Comment: A solução do @bfavaretto também foi legal sim. Eu utilizaria a ideia dele e lançaria dentro de uma `function` (pois a ideia que expressei na resposta foi pensando que a operação seria reutilizada, e não apenas ser usada uma vez). Pois, se a operação fosse realizada uma só vez, não tem por que colocar numa função - e, portanto, o exemplo dele é totalmente válido.

Comment: A diferença é que, com `Arrays`, você pode depende da posição dos elementos dentro do `DOM` e, com `Object`, você especifica qual texto quer em qual lugar, dinamicamente!.

Comment: Certo e quando você pretende marcar como solução do seu problema? Ou Nenhuma dessas respostas resolve o seu problema?